# Moishezon projectivity criterion for Moishezon spaces with canonical singularites

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, minimal-model-program

A Moishezon manifold is projective if and only if it is Kähler. This is no longer true for a singular Moishezon space. Moishezon proved a projectivity criterion for Moishezon spaces with isolated singularities. It is also known for Moishezon spaces with 1-rational singularities( Note that varieies with 1-rational singularities my do not have rational singularities in general but for  algebraic surface these two notions are same ). So it is true that a Moishezon space with canonical singularites (in the sense of the minimal model program) is projective if and only if it is Kähler.

Is  the following statement true in general?:

> Let $M$ be any compact complex variety with 1-rational singularities.
>   Then $M$ is a Moishezon space if and only if there is a proper
>   analytic subset $S⊂M$, such that $M\setminus S$ admits a complete
>   singular Kähler-Einstein metric with negative Ricci curvature?

In fact the existence of a Kähler-Einstein metric has been verified for varieties of general type with  mild singularites, so this question might be natural to ask for 1-rational singularites

The motivation is the mild singular version of [my recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275930/compactification-of-the-moduli-space-of-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds-with-negative-constant)

**Definition**: A compact complex space $M$ is Moishezon if and only if there exists a weakly positive coherent $\mathcal O_M$-module of rank 1 on $M$.

**Definition:** An algebraic variety $X$ is said to have 1-rational singularities, if the following
two conditions holds true

(1) $X$ is normal,

(2) for every resolution $f : \tilde X \to X$ of $X$ we have $R^1f_∗\mathcal O_{\tilde X} = 0$

Comment: Canonical singularities (or even klt singularities) are rational. So if the answer is known for rational singularities......

Comment: Ahh, this Kähler-Einstein metric again drunk me I wrote silly question, I apologize. The answer(in edited version) must be correspond to relation between semi log canonical singularities and 1-rational singularities. If you know, please let me know.